# Truffle contract.deployed does not get the latest instance deployed

Tags: truffle, dapps, nodejs, truffle-contract

I am developing a back-end DApp using truffle and nodejs on a private network. My application call Contract.deployed() and print the address of the obtained Contract. When I call **truffle migrate --reset**, my app still get the old contract. 
So here is the test:

1. I deploy the the contract
2. I start my application
3. I **migrate --reset** the contract
4. My application execute Contract.deployed() and gets the old version of the contract.

So here is the code :

For the example, I used a simple contract provided with the truffle toolbox.

```
truffle unbox metacoin 
truffle deploy

   Deploying 'MetaCoin'
   --------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xf8c0dbc30008e48a023bbb5678773b8220563520f73a38cdfbe5fbef59c19253
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
   > account:             0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d
   > balance:             1000000000
   > gas used:            358572
   > gas price:           0 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0 ETH

   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:                   0 ETH
```

And I have a small software that query the Metacoin.deployed() address every 5 second. I added a prompt to debug and see if I can update the address manually

```
const WEB3_PROVIDER = "http://localhost:22000";

let Web3        = require('web3'),
    contract    = require("truffle-contract"),
    path        = require('path'),
    MetaCoinAbi = require(path.join(__dirname, "../smartContract/build/contracts/MetaCoin"));

let provider    = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(WEB3_PROVIDER);
let MetaCoin = contract(MetaCoinAbi);
MetaCoin.setProvider(provider);
let metaCoinAddress;

const readline = require('readline');

function status(){

    let metaCoinPromise;
    if (typeof metaCoinAddress !== 'undefined'){
        metaCoinPromise = MetaCoin.at(metaCoinAddress);
    }else{
        metaCoinPromise = MetaCoin.deployed();
    }

    metaCoinPromise.then(async metaCoin=>{
        console.log("The deployed MetaCoin contract is at "+metaCoin.address)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

// query the metacoin address every 5 sec
setInterval(status, 5000);

// command promt
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: '> '
});


rl.prompt("");
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  switch (line.trim().split(" ")[0]) {
    case 'address':
        metaCoinAddress = line.trim().split(" ")[1]
        console.log("metaCoinAddress is set at "+metaCoinAddress);
        break;
    default:
      console.log(`Unknown command '${line.trim()}'`);
      break;
  }
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log('Closing');
  process.exit(0);
});
```

my package.json in case of

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ethlint": "^1.2.3",
    "truffle-contract": "^4.0.4",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.4",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.37",
  }
}
```

Here is the output of the test

```
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
>> deploy the new contract with truffle deploy --reset >> output new contract at 0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90
>> it should be the new address?
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xeE5d7863B98eB793f6d2b77d51FC0fD2474fE55f

>> set the new Contract address to prove it can access it
>> address 0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90
The deployed MetaCoin contract is at 0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90
```

When I stop and restart my application it start with the new address. (0xaD0a14caC7eb984a7b7F1436Ce2ED79Bc7c2fF90)

Is it an expected behavior?
Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how things are supposed to work. The contract's ABI is read only once at the beginning.

```
MetaCoinAbi = require(path.join(__dirname, "../smartContract/build/contracts/MetaCoin"));
```

Further changes are ignored.

For a dynamic behavior you have to re-read the ABI file and recreate the MetaCoin object.